# Chat Enhancement - Browser Plugin for Linux Users

Tags: discussion, chat, notifications, linux, addon

Me and a couple of other people have been hard at work to bring something brilliant to all Linux users who frequent the chat rooms on StackExchange sites.

**Introducing...** [chromify-osd](https://launchpad.net/chromify-osd)!

[image]

As you can see, the plugin allows browser scripts to create `libnotify` messages. In fact, when used in conjunction with the provided Chrome extension, it will automatically be used instead of the default WebKit desktop notifications.

## Questions

**So what does this all mean?**
It means better integration with the OS.

**What's supported?**
Currently, any Mozilla-based browser and Google Chrome.

**How do I install it?**

- For Chrome/ium, you can install it directly from the Chrome web store [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmgdlkljbfeeinemfljcbmnkmbeligmn).
- Firefox users need the NPAPI plugin in `~/.mozilla/plugins`. (Choose the right one for your platform [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~chromify-osd-team/chromify-osd/npapi/files/head:/bin/).) Then install [this](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/chromify-osd/greasemonkey/download/head:/chromifyosd.user.js-20110429033014-m01o5whmwder8gdi-1/chromify-osd.user.js) UserScript.

I also set up an APT repository for Ubuntu users: `http://apt.quickmediasolutions.com/`

Comment: Linux? Never heard of it. Any good?

Comment: Seriously though, nice work!

Comment: @Pekka: Don't say that to the [Ask Ubuntu community](http://askubuntu.com)!

Comment: @George Ubuntu? I think I installed that on my Windows once. Graphics sucked so I uninstalled it. Plus it didn't work

Comment: @Pekka: Are you sure you're thinking of the right thing? Ubuntu is an *operating system*. You don't install it in Windows (unless you're using a virtualization solution).

Comment: @George don't be silly. Everyone knows there is only one operating system and that is Windows. Everything else (Linux, Mac OS) is just on top of that to give the windows a different look and make the icons look different

Comment: @Pekka: Uhm... I'm assuming that was a joke. But seriously. I use Ubuntu **daily** and I can say with certainty that it *far exceeds* Windows in features, performance, and reliability. (And yes, I used to be a Windows user for years.)

Comment: @George just trolling ya :) I know Ubuntu well and like it. I'm just married to Windows with some key apps, otherwise, I'd have switched long ago. Although Windows 7 *is* the best Windows ever made, hands down, they've done a lot of things right there

Comment: The only thing Windows can do that Ubuntu cannot is make people shell out $$$ for a bloated, poorly-supported operating system :) *(As you can see, I'm not a Windows enthusiast)*

Comment: @George I'm sure I'll end up working with it one day. At the moment, though, the Linux world lacks some key apps for me (photo and illustration software with CMYK support, support for my old scanner....) but that'll change in time, no doubt. Although for the record, Windows 7 really was the first Microsoft product I felt not like a waste of money buying.

Comment: @Pekka: I know. I feel sympathetic for people who are stuck on a platform because of a certain app or service. I have a scanner that doesn't work in Linux too.

Comment: Oh boy, like I need *another* way for Marc's chat notifications to distract me! :)

Comment: @marcog now you can be distracted three ways! 1. Through the page; 2. Through Chrome's native desktop notification; 3. Through the plugin.

Comment: Heh.. wait 'till they write an API for chat. Then we'll have no end of distractions.

Comment: Wait, Ubuntu is a Linux now? [When did that start](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/unix-and-ubuntu-why-both/)?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmgdlkljbfeeinemfljcbmnkmbeligmn link broken.